# Django Join in Admin View

Tags: python, django

I was wondering if someone could help me. I'm new to Django and python as a whole, so be nice!

I was wondering if I could make the ServerRole.name appear on the admin view of Server, code below:

## Models.py

```
class ServerRole(models.Model):
    server_role_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'serverRole'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.server_role_id)

class Server(models.Model):
    server_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    server_role_id = models.IntegerField()
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    is_online = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.server_id)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'server'
```

## Admin.py

```
class ServerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('server_id', 'server_role_id', 'hostname', 'ip', 'is_online', 'date_added', 'status')

class ServerRoleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('server_role_id', 'name')

admin.site.register(Server, ServerAdmin)
admin.site.register(ServerRole, ServerRoleAdmin)
```

Comment: Why do you not have it setup as a foreign key?

Comment: You mean making the name a foreign key?

Comment: No server_role should be a foreign key on the server model

Comment: That's pretty much it. Now you can change the unicode attribute to point to the name and you have what you need